# There is chrases in some google related in Firebase Chraslytics

Tags: android

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{videostatusmaker.videostatus.boo/com.example.abc.activity.PlayVideoActivity}: 
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3190)
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3300)
    android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000 (ActivityThread.java:211)
    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1705)
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
    android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:145)
    android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6946)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1404)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1199)
Caused by java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    androidx.collection.SimpleArrayMap.put (SimpleArrayMap.java)
    com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzin.zza (zzin.java)
    com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzid.onActivityCreated (zzid.java)
    android.app.Application.dispatchActivityCreated (Application.java:213)
    android.app.Activity.onCreate (Activity.java:1040)
    androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.onCreate (ComponentActivity.java)
    androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onCreate (ComponentActivity.java)
    androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate (FragmentActivity.java)
    androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate (AppCompatActivity.java)
    com.example.videomaster.activity.PlayVideoActivity.onCreate (PlayVideoActivity.java)
    android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6575)
    android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1134)
    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3143)
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3300)
    android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000 (ActivityThread.java:211)
    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1705)
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
    android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:145)
    android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6946)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1404)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

I don't know what is the error related but in Firebase Crashlytics its saw in huge amount! So, I am just confusing what is the problem in coding or in library?

I am using these google libraries:

```
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:19.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.7.2'
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.11.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0'
```

Its not just in one activity or screen but its also throwing in other screens also. I don't know what happnes but I just need to know is it serious?

Answer (score 0):

Google has an [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new) where you can report problems with their libraries. Make sure you provide enough information to help library developers triage the issue, ideally submitting a sample project that consistently reproduces the problem.

Comment: How can I create an issue without properly knowing what an issue?!

Comment: That's for the library developers to figure out what exactly is the issue with the library code. You can help by submitting a bug report.